# T4 subtemplates TransformText() not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I have a very strange situation with T4 templates.

I have a collection of strings which are representing entities to be generated with a template. Here I have such code:

```
<#@ template  debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ include file="EntityTemplate.tt" #>

<#
// kinda var Names = new List<string>();

foreach (name in Names)
{
    EntityTemplate template = new EntityTemplate();
    template.EntityClassName = name;
    template.PropertyActions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ConfigActionBase>
    { 
        new DefaultAction,
        new ValidateAction
    };
    ProcessContent(name + ".cs", template.TransformText());
}
#>
```

DefaultAction and ValidateAction are inherited from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation and override TransformText() method like this:

```
<#+public class ValidateAction: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation
{
    public override string TransformText()
    {#>
        public void Foo()
        { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    <#+return GenerationEnvironment.ToString(); // BREAKPOINT HERE
    }
}#>
```

And ProcessContent() method is:

```
public void ProcessContent(string outputFileName, string content)
{
    string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
    string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory, outputFileName);
    File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, content);
}
```

And here is my EntityTemplate class:

```
<#+
public class EntityTemplate : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation
{
    public string EntityClassName { get; set; }

    public System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation> PropertyActions { get; set; }

    public override string TransformText()
    {#>

        namespace MyGenerated
        {
            public class <#= EntityClassName #>
            {
            <#+foreach (var action in PropertyActions)
                action.TransformText();#>
            }
        }

        <#+return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();
    } 

}#>
```

So, the problem is that my template generating only class name and empty braces and no any actions generated code (Foo methods). As we see, Actions are subtemplates. But if I insert breakpoint to the line commented "BREAKPOINT HERE" I see all needed code inside GenerationEnvironment object. And if I introduce separate variable and return try its value, the problem still here: value is set, but nothing is rendered to output.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution quickly :) just changed this:

```
<#+foreach (var action in PropertyActions)
            action.TransformText();#>
```

to this:

```
<#+foreach (var action in PropertyActions)
            #><#=action.TransformText()#>;#>
```